# current user id saved from _form or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise to manage users and my goal get the current user to be saved with the created record.

I have tried to save the current user in the controller or in the _form, but either ways it has failed!

Thank you all for your help.

My record Model

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Associations
  belongs_to :user


  # Validations
  validates :title, :user, presence: true
end
```

My record Controller

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_record, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @record = Record.new(record_params)

    if @record.save
      redirect_to @record
    else
      @records = Record.all
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @record.update(record_params)
      flash[:notice] = "The record was updated successfully"
      redirect_to @record
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def find_record
      @record = Record.find(params[:id])
    end

    def record_params
      params.require(:record).permit(:title, :description, :user_id).merge(user: current_user) # as suggested 
    end
end
```

My Rspec

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe RecordsController do
  let(:record) { create(:record) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:title) { "Some title I would like to put in my record" }
  let(:description) { "description I would like to put in my record" }


  describe "#create" do
    it "creates a new record with the given title and description" do
      expect do
        post :create, record: { title: title, description: description, user_id: user }
      end.to change { Record.count }.by(1)

      expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns[:record])

      expect(assigns[:record].title).to eq(title)
      expect(assigns[:record].description).to eq(description)
    end

    it "fails to create a record and returns to the index page" do
      expect(post :create, record: { description: description }).to render_template(:index)
      expect(assigns[:records]).to eq(Record.all)
    end
  end

  describe "#update" do
    it "find the records and sets the new given values" do
      put :update, { id: record.id, record: { title: title, description: description } }

      record.reload
      expect(record.title).to eq(title)
      expect(record.description).to eq(description)

      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("The record was updated successfully")
    end

    it "fails to create a record and returns to the edit page" do
      expect(put :update, { id: record.id, record: { title: "" } }).to render_template(:edit)
    end
  end
end
```

Now with the current user being saved Rspec throws me errors in create and update:

```
1) RecordsController#create creates a new record with the given title and description
     Failure/Error: post :create, record: { title: title, description: description, user_id: user }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:42:in `record_params'
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:9:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/records_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/records_controller_spec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  2) RecordsController#create fails to create a record and returns to the index page
     Failure/Error: expect(post :create, record: { description: description }).to render_template(:index)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:42:in `record_params'
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:9:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/records_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  3) RecordsController#update find the records and sets the new given values
     Failure/Error: put :update, { id: record.id, record: { title: title, description: description } }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:42:in `record_params'
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:20:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/records_controller_spec.rb:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  4) RecordsController#update fails to create a record and returns to the edit page
     Failure/Error: expect(put :update, { id: record.id, record: { title: "" } }).to render_template(:edit)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:42:in `record_params'
     # ./app/controllers/records_controller.rb:20:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/records_controller_spec.rb:72:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: there is nowhere you are setting the `@record.user` to be the current user. Or, where are you doing this?

Comment: You are not using anywhere `current_user`. Please post the code where you intend to save the current user id to the record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to `bo-oz`'s answer (which should work), you also need to look into [`foreign keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). Trying to set `record_id` in your `record` form simply won't work, and I think demonstrates a misunderstanding in your interpretation of how the system works with this important piece of technology.

Specifically, you need to make sure your **`user_id`** attribute is populated before you save the new `record`. This is a *relational database* specification, not Rails:

[image]

Each time you create an association in Rails, it *has* to have foreign keys set in the database to enable [`ActiveRecord`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) (the object association builder inside Rails) to combine the appropriate data together:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :records
end

#app/models/record.rb
class Record < ActiveRecord:Base
   #see diagram above -- this has to have user_id in the schema :)
   belongs_to :user
end
```

--

The problem you're having is that **you're not setting your `user` foreign key** when you create a record.

Your records table *should* have a `user_id` foreign key, so that when Rails pulls out a `Record` object, it will be able to find the `User` who's associated to it.

As `bo-oz` explained, you can achieve this by setting `@record.user`, you can *also* set it in the params:

```
#app/controllers/records_controller.rb
class RecordsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @record = Record.new record_params
      @record.save ..........
   end

   private

   def record_params
      params.require(:record).permit(......).merge(user: current_user)
   end
end
```

Both these answers would set the appropriate foreign key inside your new `Record` object.

Comment: It seemed simpler to use in the params and its working, but my Rspec is throwing me some errors.

Comment: It's saying it can't authenticate `nilClass`, meaning you've not got a `user` object set for your tests. I've not got huge experience with that side of things -- maybe this will help: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to assign the user to the new record:

```
  def create
    @record = Record.new(record_params)
    @record.user = current_user

    if @record.save
      redirect_to @record
    else
      @records = Record.all
      render 'index'
    end
  end
```